# CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.button onClick function accessing editor content

Tags: ckeditor

I'm working on a dialog for a button in `CKEditor 4.3`. In the click handler version, I would like to update the content of the editor, but so far I only found functions to access the dialog elements. I'm looking for something similar than `this.getParentEditor().getSelection().getSelectedElement()` which works fine in the `onShow` function. Is it possible and how to access the content directly from the `onClick` function?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it sorted out. I was able to get access via the `this.getDialog().getParentEditor()` function call.